# How can i remove the quotation marks from this tuple? and how can i homogeneous the list

Tags: python, list, parsing, tuples

e.g. i have:

```
"('orange', 'apple','banana')"
```

i got this as a result of:

```
str(tuple(fruit_list))
```

how can  remove the outer quotation marks?

EDIT:

in my list i have e.g.:
list1 = ['orange',"fruit",'banana']

you can see some has double quotation marks, how can i replace it with ' . I have tried:

```
[i.replace('"', '') for i in list1 ]
```

but doesn't work

Comment: You almost never want to use a string representation of a tuple for anything. What is that you _really_ want? Comma-separated fruits?

Comment: You can't - they're part of the string representation

Comment: After removing do you still want string or a tuple

Comment: As ForceBru has said - it's part of the string representation. If you want to display the result then print() it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete those quotation marks as they are part of the string representation itself.

If you want to display the result then `print()` it.

This should do it:

`print(', '.join(result))`

This creates a comma-delimited string of each list entry:

`orange, apple, banana`

Comment: You'd just have to hope no fruit contains a quotation mark.

Comment: What if you just replace the first character and last character of str. Then it shouldn't matter whether fruit contains quotation marks

Answer (score 0):

Because they are parts of string representation, you can't. When you `print(fruitlist)`, this automatically works

EDIT: Just saw that the comments say the same, but I wasn't looking at the comments while writing the post.

Answer (score 0):

the "('orange', 'apple','banana')" isnt a tuple, its a String you need to checkout the function/method that are returning that string;

If you cant modify the method/function that returns this String you need to create a function do disassemble the String and create a tuple from String content.